# How to get the best selling item with excel function

Tags: excel, function

I would like to get an excel function which will get me the best selling item name I tried with Index, vlookup, countif etc but I'ts not working. Sumifs() so far so good but in this case I must give a criteria

For example:

```
A1: Item 1    B1: 10pcs
A2: Item 2    B2: 40pcs
A3: Item 1    B3: 5pcs
A4: Item 1    B4: 10pcs
```

In this case I want to get "Item2" which is the best selling product

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so attempt 2,

only way I could do it was with helper columns, see image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XecZ.jpg

In E1 I used:

```
{=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$4=D1,SUBSTITUTE($B$1:$B$4,"pcs","")+0,0))}
```

And in G1 I used:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$2,MATCH(MAX($E$1:$E$2),$E$1:$E$2,0),1)
```

I know not everyone likes helper columns :s

Comment: It's working perfectly :)
Don't worry about the helper columns I'm going to hide them :)

Thank you